# Build single SQL query using join .is it possible?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 6 tables and I am going to do a single sql statement:

```
1)participant
  ***********
  +id_participant
  +id_poste
  +name
  +email

2) profile_formaion
  ****************
  +id_poste
  +id_formation

3) formation
  *********
  +id_formation
  +lable

4) poste
  *********
  +id_poste
  +label

5) session
  *********
  +id_session
  +id_formaion
  +lable

6) session_composition
  *********
  +id_session
  +id_participant
```

`EXAMPLE:`

DATA:participant

```
1 | 2 | user1 | user1@mail.com
2 | 3 | user2 | user2@mail.com
```

DATA:profile_formation

```
2 | 3
2 | 4
```

DATA:formation

```
1 |formation1
2 |formation2
3 |formation3
4 |formation4
```

DATA: poste

```
1 |Poste1
2 |Poste2
3 |Poste3
```

DATA:session

```
1 |1   /* id_session 1 to id_formation 1  and id_formation=1 is formation1 */
```

DATA:session_composition

```
1 |2  /* id_session 1 to id_participant 2 */
```

I am trying:

```
SELECT 
    participant.id_participant,
    participant.id_poste,
    participant.name,
    participant.email,
    formation.lable 
FROM participant
INNER JOIN profile_formaion ON
    profile_formaion.id_poste = participant.id_poste 
INNER JOIN formation ON
    formation.id_formation = profile_formaion.id_formation
```

How can I use sql statement(join) to get the result:

DATA:result

```
1 | 2 | user1 | user1@mail.com | poste2|formation3
1 | 2 | user1 | user1@mail.com | poste2|formation4
2 | 3 | user2 | user2@mail.com | poste3|formation1 // How can we join to get it.
```

Comment: Yes. How depends on your relationships. Are they all required or some optional? If some are optional do you want the records from participant where the optional relations don't exist or can they be ignored?

Comment: Mission: Impossible. Code golf? Note, if you put it into a schema tool (Access and MySQL Workbench [free] have one), it can be easier to discern the relationships visually, which can help you see the joins you need.

Comment: @Jeroen some are optional. Yes I want to record from participant.

Comment: INNER JOIN on the required relationships and LEFT JOIN on the optional ones. Surely you're not going to ask me to do it for you? This is basic SQL.

Comment: Why is `poste3` related to `formation1` in the results? That is not shown in the tables.

Comment: if you look at DATA:participant 2 | 3 | user2 | user2@mail.com the post is 3 = poste3 (check table poste)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your not averse to using unions, you can always do this:

```
select
    participant.id_participant,
    participant.id_poste,
    participant.name,
    participant.email,
    poste.label,
    formation.lable
from
    participant
    inner join poste on participant.id_poste = poste.id_poste
    inner join profile_formaion on participant.id_poste = profile_formaion.id_poste
    inner join formation on profile_formaion.id_formation = formation.id_formation

union all

select
    participant.id_participant,
    participant.id_poste,
    participant.name,
    participant.email,
    poste.label,
    formation.lable
from
    participant
    inner join poste on participant.id_poste = poste.id_poste
    inner join session_composition on participant.id_participant = session_composition.id_participant
    inner join session on session_composition.id_session = session.id_session
    inner join formation on session.id_formaion = formation.id_formation
```